# Azure blob storage life cycle management - set filter at container level

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have azure storage account on which I'm enabling life cycle management.
Is it possible to set filter at container level?

eg Container/folder1/x.txt
Container/folder2/y.txt

I want the life management **filter set to be applied at container level** instead of filtering by blob name prefix.

Answer (score 4):

The only filter on container level is like below:

Suppose you have 3 containers, like `container-1`, `container-2`, `container3`, then you can set the filter as `container-`, then the policy is only applied to `container-1`, `container-2`.

So in your case, you can directly set the filter as the container name, like `Container`.

Answer (score 4):

To apply filtering at the container level, simply specify the container name as blob prefix.

[image]